# Make a movieclip follow mouse after 2 seconds in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I'm trying to get a movieclip "orb_mc" to move  along the same ordinates of the mouse pointer after a delay of 2 seconds that is to say there should be a 2 seconds delay before the orb moves to the same position as the pointer. Below is my code- everything is working fine except the delay.

```
import flash.events.Event;

Mouse.hide();
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, moveThatMouse);

function moveThatMouse(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    wand.x = stage.mouseX;
    wand.y = stage.mouseY;
    evt.updateAfterEvent();
}

var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(2000);
        var speed:Number=10;

        orb_mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,follow);
        function follow(e:Event):void{
            myTimer.start();
           orb_mc.x -= (orb_mc.x - mouseX) / speed;
            orb_mc.x = orb_mc.x +2;
           orb_mc.y -= (orb_mc.y - mouseY) / speed;
            orb_mc.y = orb_mc.y +3;

        }
```

Comment: This questions unclear.  Move a little bit along? What does that mean? Tell exactly what you want to have happen. If you can't explain precisely to a human what you want, you certainly won't be able to get a computer to understand you.

Comment: Am I to understand that the movement is exactly as you desire, but you just don't want it to respond to the mouse for the first 2 seconds of running the .swf? Or do you mean you want the orb to lag 2 behind where the mouse was?

Comment: exactly Neal I want it to lag 2 seconds behind were the mouse was. Sorry for not been clear . I will try and clerify my question

Comment: Ok. I think I am beginning to understand. But help me understand also why you are incrementing the orb's x/y coords with a constant +2 and +3?

Comment: Okay that was the only amateur solution I could come up with to make sure the orb is not directly under the pointer but a few distance away from the tip of the mouse pointer once it travels to the were the mouse pointer is

Comment: Oh that's fine. Nothing wrong with that. Just wasn't sure. That looks fine

Comment: Ok. So what should happen if I move the mouse for 5 seconds in a straight line from right to left?

Comment: The orb stays put for 2 seconds, right?

Comment: Then what happens immediately after 2 seconds, at 2.01 seconds? Should the orb then go directly to where the mouse is and follow for the next 3 seconds?

Comment: Or should the orb wait until the mouse stops and then wait 2 more seconds and then slide to where the mouse is?

Comment: okay to put simply, the orb should not move until the mouse pointer is stationary for a second that's truly what I intended  to achieve

Comment: I understand your problem now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't bother using a timer in this case. Per your response to my comments, I understand that you simply want the `orb_mc` to travel smoothly to the point at which the mouse stops moving. Of course you could simply say something to the effect of "if mouse isn't moving, send orb to mouse" but the problem with that is you will get these jerky motions because there will be these little moments when the mouse movement doesn't register (especially when the mouse is slowing down to begin moving the other direction). This is why you want to add some sort of delay. So the way I would approach this is to basically have a counter go up each frame, and be reset to 0 whenever the mouse moves.

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event; 
Mouse.hide(); 

var mouseCounter: int = 0;
var mouseDelay: int = 20; // how many frames the mouse must stay still before the follow code is run.    
// var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(2000); won't need this with my method.
var speed:Number=10; 

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMove);

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,follow);

// set counter back to zero whenever the mouse is moved. 
function mouseMove(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    wand.x = stage.mouseX;
    wand.y = stage.mouseY;
    e.updateAfterEvent();
    mouseCounter = 0;
}

function follow(e:Event):void{
    // increment the counter each frame
    mouseCounter++; 

    // now run the follow block if the mouse has been still for enough frames. 
    if (mouseCounter >= mouseDelay)
    {
        //myTimer.start();  won't need this for my method. 
        orb_mc.x -= (orb_mc.x - mouseX) / speed;
        orb_mc.x += 2;
        orb_mc.y -= (orb_mc.y - mouseY) / speed;
        orb_mc.y += 3;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it would be extremely helpful if you could post the lines of code on how I can achieve that. Its been brain racking for me.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance but is the solution based on the assumption that  I am working with a class file ? because working with class file is not really my strength yet

Comment: You don't know it, but your main class is actually the stage. And you are writing in it when you use its timeline for your code.  This should be copy and paste and should work fine. Play around with the mouseDelay as it will depend on the frame rate you choose.

Comment: Okay, though I'm getting an error that "the private attribute may be used only on a class property definitions"

Comment: Ok. Ditch that private then

Comment: Okay I guess classes is the way to go, that's the trend now. Anyway i executed the code but got an error from the line were you added a listener to the stage for mouseMove, error says "call to a possibly undefined method addEventHandler through a a reference with static type flash.display:stage "

Comment: Lol okay, erm no compiler errors, orb moving but still no 2 seconds delay and output error says "ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on MouseParallaxfloatingorbd_fla::MainTimeline/mouseMove(). Expected 0, got 1.   Note "MouseParallaxfloatingorbd_fla" is the document name

Comment: what is your framerate?

Comment: Oh, and again, how are creating the orb? just in the GUI?

Comment: yea it alreay exists on the stage as an instance

Comment: Ok. Yeah let me see the rest of that code in the timeline.

Comment: I need your help getting my orb to be responsive from the main timeline :)  What is your orb called?  Does it have a linkage in its properties panel etc.? The instance name must be orb_mc, right? How did you set that? The last time i coded in the timeline was in AS2 which was totally different.  Or do you just want me to show you the light with classes?

Comment: Erm just orb_mc, it has no linkages

Comment: so, you made a circle.  then selected it and converted it to a symbol.  then you chose MovieClip, and named it orb_mc.  and then in the code, you can just refer to orb_mc.x and it works fine?

Comment: Yep that's precisely all I did

Comment: Okay thanks i can't wait for this to finally start working

Comment: import flash.events.Event;

Mouse.hide();
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, moveThatMouse);

function moveThatMouse(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    wand.x = stage.mouseX;
    wand.y = stage.mouseY;
    evt.updateAfterEvent();
}   ------this is the only code that precedes it, it is a custom mouse

Comment: oops! just got it.

Comment: Okay I will be glad to send the whole file to you i am working in Flash cs5, if you give me ur email address

Comment: I had to change the instance name in the properties panel of the instance on the stage... i had been changing the name of the library one (which is the class)

Comment: I'll just post the final code that is working and you should be off and running

Comment: Lol okay phew that's good to hear, so we can now move forward

Comment: Okay thanks so much for your patience, I will implement it in the morning and vote you up

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117017/discussion-between-solowalker-and-neal-davis).